# bashscript Heredoc + FTP error

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, heredoc

I try to do this

```
 #!/bin/bash

 ftp "$HOST"$3"/"$2"/" <<EOD
        #toggle Interactive mode
        prompt off
        lcd $5"/"$4
        mget "$4"*
        exit
 EOD
```

I get the following error

> syntax error: unexpected end of file

When I changed it to or any other possibility

```
ftp "$HOST"$3"/"$2"/" <<<EOD
            #toggle Interactive mode
            prompt off
            lcd $5"/"$4
            mget "$4"*
            exit
     EOD
```

I get

```
./download.sh: line 31: 87621 Segmentation fault: 11  ftp "$HOST"$3"/"$2"/" <<< EOD
./download.sh: line 20: prompt: command not found
./download.sh: line 21: lcd: command not found
./download.sh: line 22: mget: command not found
```

I am not sure how to fix this. What am I supposed to doooo O_O

Answer (score 2):

On my Mac, the segmentation faults were produced by the comments in the script. Removing the lines with the trailing # would make it work.

Answer (score 0):

many interactive commands don't really deal well with piped input. maybe try http://www.columbia.edu/kermit/ftpscripts.html ?

that said, many others seem to have had success doing what you're doing (e.g. http://www.unix.com/unix-advanced-expert-users/4189-automated-ftp.html ), so maybe you just have a quoting problem? try changing the command (`ftp "$HOST"$3"/"$2"/"`) to just `cat` to see if the shell is properly passing there here-doc to it?

this, too, may lend insight if you end up needing to supply a password: http://www.stratigery.com/scripting.ftp.html

Comment: I actually tried cat and shell does properly pass heredoc. I did read that article as it was one of the first one to return from google but it was of little help. The ftp server does not require any credential at all

Comment: here-docs do not automatically strip whitespace. what if you try it with `cat` and then copy-paste the output into an ftp session? does that work? (just trying to isolate the fault)

Comment: your `<<<` version would definitely fail the `cat` test, as `prompt` etc. are clearly getting run by the shell.

Comment: re: leading space, that's what `<<-` is for: (per `man bash`) "If the redirection operator is <<-, then all leading tab characters are stripped from input lines and  the  line  containing  delimiter.   This allows  here-documents within shell scripts to be indented in a natural fashion."

Comment: you really shouldn't be able to get bash to segfault. if you're up to it, it might be worth it to use a debugger to figure out where that's happening and report a bug on your distro.